# Was iddah applicable to Saffiyah bint huayy and zainab bint Jash

Tags: prophets, iddah, wives-of-the-prophet

Safiyyah bint huay and Zainab bint Jahsh were Prophets wives.

Safiyyah's husband was killed. Did she adhere to iddah before marriage to prophet? Was Iddah applicable to her because of her parent faith Judaism?

Zainab was divorced from zaid bin Harris, did she follow waiting period before marriage to prophet?

If both had waiting period why dont the attackers on prophet forego this thing or muslim debators of Islam fail to mention this? **3 months waiting works against lust**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Hadith record that the prophet proposed to Zaynab bint Jahsh after her iddah:

> لما **انقضت عدة** زينب، قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم لزيد: فاذكرها علي
>
> When the **'Iddah** of Zainab **was over**, the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said to Zaid: 'Make, mention of me to her (for marriage)'.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1428b)</sup>

As for Safiyyah bint Huyayy, she was a prisoner of war and the ruling for that case is that they observe *istibra* rather than *iddah*, which is the passage of one menses (see [here](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/12/112)).
It is explicitly recorded that the prophet married her after that:

> فخرج بها، حتى بلغنا سد الصهباء **حلت، فبنى بها** رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم
>
> When we reached a place called Sidd-as-Sahba, Safiya **became clean** (from her menses) **then** Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) **married her**.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4211)</sup>

As for your last question, it is the job of Islam's enemies to criticize it in anyway including by making baseless allegations and then to insist on it. Why do you care what they say?

Answer (score -2):

After Zayd separated from Zainab and the days of 'Uddah passed, God Almighty ordered the Holy Prophet (PBUH) that he himself should marry Zainab. The reason for this marriage by God was that another custom of the pre-Islamic era had to be abolished. At that time, one of the pre-existing customs of the pre-Islamic age was that marriage with a adopted son was forbidden and forbidden.

They considered the adopted woman as a real boy, but the Prophet of Islam (PBUH) should have abolished this custom as well. Therefore, he was commanded by God to marry the divorced wife of his adopted son in order to eliminate that false tradition, and this order was communicated to the Prophet through revelation - verse 37 of the parties. (6) Later, Zainab was superior to the other wives of the Prophet (PBUH) because her marriage to the Prophet (PBUH) was done by divine command. (7)
6. Parties, verse 37.
7. Ibn Sa'd, the same, vol. 8, p. 103.